# Removing background from image in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, remove.bg

So I currently have an app that allows the user to take a photo. I would like it so that once they've taken the photo of themself, the app will remove the background of the image (like remove.bg) and present it as a transparent PNG. I would use remove.bg's API but you only get 50 free credits a month and I would likely be processing more than that. I've looked into OpenCV and Tensorflow but I can't really seem to get any success with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You'd probably have to setup a backend for that, if you want to remove the background. Once the user takes a photo the image gets sent to your backend where it gets processed by OpenCV and sent back backgroundless. Django or Nodejs make good backend options.